# Calculator program for postfix-expressions

Tags: c++

The program should read a postfix expression consisting of numbers and operators and compute the result. I try using `string` but I keep getting a result that is way off. Can you please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "StackADT.h"
#include <stack>
using namespace std;
#include <string>;


bool isOperator(string);
int calculate (int, char, int);
void display (int, string, int, int);

int main(){

    string expr;

    int operand2 = 0;
    int operand1 = 0;
    string thisOperator;
    int value;
    int result;

    cout << "Evaluates a postfix expression(to Quit)." << endl;
    cin >> expr;
    //while(expr != "-1")
    {
        //getline( cin, expr,'\n' ); 

        int exprSize = expr.size();
        const int siz = 10;
        char expr2[siz];

        for (int i = 0; i < expr.length; i++)
        {
            expr2[i] = expr[i];
        }

        Stack<int> stack;

        int index = 0;


        while (index < exprSize){

            if (!isOperator(expr[index]) )
            {
                stack.pushStack(expr[index]);
            }

            else
            {
                stack.popStack (operand2);
                stack.popStack (operand1);

                thisOperator = expr[index];
                value = calculate (operand1, thisOperator[index], operand2);
                stack.pushStack(value);
            }

            index++;
        }

         result = stack.popStack (operand1);

          display(operand1, thisOperator, operand2, result );

        // cout << "Evaluates a postfix expression(to Quit)." << endl;
        // cin >> expr;
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}




void display (int op1, string operat, int op2, int result){

    cout << op1 << operat << op2 << " = " << result;

}

bool isOperator(char token )
{
    if(token == '-' || token == '+' || token == '*' || token == '/')
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

int calculate (int op1, char operat, int op2){

    switch (operat)
    {

    case '/': return op1 / op2;
        break;

    case '+': return op1 + op2;
        break;

    case '*': return op1 * op2;
        break;

    case '-': return op1 - op2;
        break;

    default: cout << "Cant / by zero" << endl;
        break;
    }
}
```

I'm working off this; exprSize = length of string

1. createStack (stack)
2. index = 0
3. loop (index < exprSize)

   1. if (expr[index] is operand)

      1. pushStack (stack, expr[index])
   2. else // expr[index] is an operator

      1. popStack (stack, operand2)
      2. popStack (stack, operand1)
      3. operator = expr[index]
      4. value = calculate (operand1, operator, operand2)
      5. pushStack (stack, value)
   3. end if
   4. index = index + 1
4. end loop
5. popStack (stack, result)
6. return (result)

Comment: `expr.length` <- here, `length` is a function, therefore requires a set of parens to be called `expr.length()`. Also, `expr2` is never read from in your program. What is it for? (The copy is also unsafe, as `expr2` has a fixed length of `10`, but the string `expr` might be longer.)

Comment: `thisOperator` should probably be a `char`, not a `string`. There are problems related to this in the else-case of the while-loop.

Comment: Some error handling is missing or misleading, e.g. the `"Cant / by zero"` message is never printed as it stands, but should be when the operator is `/` and `op2` is `0` in `calculate`.

Comment: There's a lot of errors. An obvious one is `expr[index]`. This doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Please a more specific question than "what is wrong?" What input causes wrong behavior? What did you discover when you debugged the program?

Comment: thank everyone the main problem was that i did have to parse it to int and put in a array and that is way off result was the ascii value..smh thank again